# how to increment or decrement elements of an array

Tags: arrays, sorting

I want to increase or decrease elements of an array during a condition

for example:

```
char array[5];

if (condition)
{
   increase array elemets
}

if (condition)
{
   decrease array elemets
}
```

Comment: By increase do you mean add new data or increase size?

Comment: @Sid increase size

Comment: Arrays in most languages are constant size.  Any specific language you are targeting here?  Most languages also have dynamic arrays for this purpose, so you don't need to manually increase the size.

Answer (score 0):

In python, u can use push/pop to do so
example to add an element is an array:

```
 if(len(mylist) < 5):
   mylist = [1,2,3,4]
   mylist.append("Honda")
 print("mylist")
```

o/p: 1,2,3,4,Honda

to remove an element from the array:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4]
if(len(mylist) < 5):
   mylist.pop()
   #pass the index of the list to remove any particular element
print("mylist")
```

o/p: 1,2,3
or similarly, u can do it in any language.

Comment: What about in C program?

Comment: I am not that expert in C, refer this https://www.sanfoundry.com/c-program-increment-element-array/ maybe u have the solution here w.r.t to C.

Comment: I am not sure if the OP mentioned python.